# “The issues <as> he sees them”

Tags: phrases

[image]

What’s the function of “as” in “the issues as he sees them”?

(The picture says “as he sees them” is an adnominal clause.)

All I can guess is that this noun phrase is the reduced form of “the issues as which he sees them” and “as he sees them” is a relative clause.

Comment: What is the full sentence? The correct analysis depends on the function of the _as_ PP in the larger construction. Without the full sentence, we cannot tell what that is.

Comment: @BillJ I think so. I found that it’s an incomplete sentence.

Comment: It's not a sentence but just a noun phrase. Note that "as he sees them" is **not** a clause but a preposition phrase. See my answer.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you, but I saw your answer yesterday.

Comment: Good. Note that the other answer is wrong, so you should not have approved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *the issues* [*as he sees them*]

"As" is a preposition, so the expression *as he sees them* is a preposition phrase with "as" as head and the **comparative** clause *he sees them* as its complement.

Without the full sentence/context, the *as* phrase is strictly speaking ambiguous. The most plausible analysis, though, is that it is a modifier in the structure of the nominal headed by "issues".

The *as* phrase specifies some aspect of what is denoted by the head noun. We are concerned here with how "he" sees the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  “as he sees them” is an adnominal clause, it modifies "issues". The whole noun phrase  means

> The issues, considered in the way in which they appear to him.

This is not a reduced form of “the issues as which he sees them”, indeed that phrase would not be grammatically valid. In fact I cannot off-hand think of a valid use of "as which".

The word "as" here means "in the way that" (which could be substituted here). Its function is to introduce the modifying clause, and indicate that it modifies the preceding term, "issues".  The word "as" (or some other word or phrase serving the same function) is required in this constriction.